# How to get the file path of a buffer?

Tags: vim, path

I know that the register % contains the full path of the current buffer. But how to get the full path of another buffer by its number?

Is there such a function/command in VIM?

I want to explain how I came to this question...

There were 2 buffers open. The first was an XML file in the left window and the other was an XSD file in the right window. I edited both of them. During the editing I wanted to validate the XML against the schema.

However the command

```
!xmllint --schema /tmp/schema.xsd %
```

of course worked well only if the current buffer was the one with the XML. So I was curious about whether it would be possible to replace `/tmp/schema.xsd` with some command or function call that would determine the full path by the buffer number. Something like:

```
!xmllint --schema getBufferPath(3) %
```

Comment: Does `:ls` help much?

Comment: @EricRenouf It only shows me the list of buffers

Comment: For me it shows the buffer number and the path to the file in it (if applicable), though it's not always the full path

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `expand()` call. For example

```
:echo expand("#2:p")
```

Will print the full path of the file in buffer #2 you can list all buffers with `:ls`

You can use other modifiers and other keywords (For full info page look at `:help expand()`)

Here is an quick excerpt:

> ```
>            When {expr} starts with '%', '#' or '<', the expansion is done
>             like for the cmdline-special variables with their associated
>             modifiers.  Here is a short overview:
>
>                    %               current file name
>                     #               alternate file name
>                     #n              alternate file name n
>                     <cfile>         file name under the cursor
>                     <afile>         autocmd file name
>                     <abuf>          autocmd buffer number (as a String!)
>                     <amatch>        autocmd matched name
>                     <sfile>         sourced script file name
>                     <slnum>         sourced script file line number
>                     <cword>         word under the cursor
>                     <cWORD>         WORD under the cursor
>                     <client>        the {clientid} of the last received
>                                     message server2client()
>             Modifiers:
>                     :p              expand to full path
>                     :h              head (last path component removed)
>                     :t              tail (last path component only)
>                     :r              root (one extension removed)
>                     :e              extension only
>
>            Example:
>                     :let &tags = expand("%:p:h") . "/tags"
>             Note that when expanding a string that starts with '%', '#' or
>             '<', any following text is ignored.  This does NOT work:
>                     :let doesntwork = expand("%:h.bak")
>             Use this:
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I executed: :!xmllint --schema #12:p #11:p and it worked. It is much shorter than to type each time the full paths.